# How to deploy a Golang/mongodb/react app on heroku?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, go, heroku

I am trying to figure out how to deploy a Golang/mongodb/react app on heroku, but I have never done it so I am kind of clueless on how to do it. I have made its own project and added the config vars that are on my .env, it has a heroku/go buildpack, but every time I do

> git push heroku main

I get this on the terminal:

```
Enumerating objects: 788, done.
Counting objects: 100% (788/788), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (728/728), done.
Writing objects: 100% (775/775), 2.16 MiB | 779.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 775 (delta 395), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/go
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Fetching stdlib.sh.v8... done
remote: -----> 
remote:        Detected go modules via go.mod
remote: ----->
```

I don't think it is giving me an error there, but if I click on open-app from heroku I get an Application error message and asks me to use
*heroku logs --tail*

And it shows me a bunch of these lines which I can't really understand:

```
2021-10-08T15:00:03.362868+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="/profile?id=615affc23cc365e3ac6cee23" host=twitter-clone-jeff.herokuapp.com request_id=58a7c915-4543-4105-95f2-063604a6e7c8 fwd="108.215.249.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-08T15:00:03.464879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="/profile?id=615affc23cc365e3ac6cee23" host=twitter-clone-jeff.herokuapp.com request_id=2f1e17e0-3c38-4d4b-9e34-5e4a8f27afcd fwd="108.215.249.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

And it finally shows me this:

```
037bc7735b fwd="108.215.249.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-08T15:13:02.688268+00:00 app[api]: Set MONGO_PASSWORD config vars by user jeffersongarcia1599@gmail.com
2021-10-08T15:13:02.688268+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user jeffersongarcia1599@gmail.com
2021-10-08T15:13:02.943260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-08T15:13:03.660069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/Twitter-Clone`
2021-10-08T15:13:04.507378+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021/10/08 15:13:04 Error loaging your .env file
2021-10-08T15:13:04.624983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-08T15:13:04.678311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-08T15:13:16.067630+00:00 app[api]: Set MY_SECRET config vars by user jeffersongarcia1599@gmail.com
2021-10-08T15:13:16.067630+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user jeffersongarcia1599@gmail.com
2021-10-08T15:13:16.408304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-08T15:13:17.103362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/Twitter-Clone`
2021-10-08T15:13:18.191933+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021/10/08 15:13:18 Error loaging your .env file
2021-10-08T15:13:18.347637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-08T15:13:18.402108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-08T15:13:35.119252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=twitter-clone-jeff.herokuapp.com request_id=133bbf4e-3dcc-44ab-ad9b-2d301868c166 fwd="108.215.249.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-08T15:20:10.885717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=twitter-clone-jeff.herokuapp.com request_id=ac8ed7a8-1137-45b8-952d-3ecea81ee645 fwd="108.215.249.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-08T15:30:38.792946+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=twitter-clone-jeff.herokuapp.com request_id=fb4bc339-5b4b-4ae2-896d-9f07f87cc16d fwd="108.215.249.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am honestly clueless since the ***git push heroku main*** does not really show any errors. I know that for Postgress databases there is like a ***Heroku Postgres*** add on, but I don't if there is a Mongo one. I have a SECRET_KEY and MONGO_PASSWORD on a .env but I also put them on the config vars. Thanks in advance! My repo in case necessary

https://github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone

Comment: *Git* is not actually involved here. It's just being used as a transport system for your programs, like the truck driver delivering packages. Heroku opens the package and either signs the acceptance form (`git push` succeeds) or doesn't (`git push` fails, look for the `remote:` lines which are Heroku telling you what it didn't like).

Comment: So, here, Heroku itself was able to handle the delivered package (the source) but then when it was *running*, something crashed; the logs give you all you get from Heroku. How to debug your program is another question entirely. In Go you'll get stack traces and running goroutines, but I have no idea if or how you can get those out of Heroku (which I've never used myself).

Comment: @torek thanks so much for your answer, yeah I am a bit clueless on how to even deploy this. I have deployed flask/psql/react and express/psql/react apps before, but never one of this ones so I don't know what to do. And I have only deployed on heroku.